# How to get screen width and height in Compose Multiplatform?

Tags: compose-multiplatform

How can I get the screen size in Compose Multiplatform *without* using expect/actual?

I have found the following explanation in https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/discussions/3225#discussioncomment-7195192:

> You can also use a Layout as your root Composable and obtain the size
> from the passed constraints. This solution doesn't depend on platform
> implementations and also gives you the exact size given to your
> Composable which could be different from the device screen size in
> some cases.
>
> Once you have that size can use a CompositionLocal to pass it down the
> composable tree

I have not been able to fully understand or successfully implement the suggested layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer at https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/discussions/3225#discussioncomment-7386013

Using that I've created a small example that might be helpful for others looking for the answer:

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.Layout

@Composable
fun App() {
    val screenSize = remember { mutableStateOf(Pair(-1, -1)) }
    Layout(
        content = {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                Text("Screen size: ${screenSize.value.first}x${screenSize.value.second}px", modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
            }
        },
        measurePolicy = { measurables, constraints ->
            // Use the max width and height from the constraints
            val width = constraints.maxWidth
            val height = constraints.maxHeight

            screenSize.value = Pair(width, height)
            println("Width: $width, height: $height")

            // Measure and place children composables
            val placeables = measurables.map { measurable ->
                measurable.measure(constraints)
            }

            layout(width, height) {
                var yPosition = 0
                placeables.forEach { placeable ->
                    placeable.placeRelative(x = 0, y = yPosition)
                    yPosition += placeable.height
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the code running on macOS, iOS simulator and Android emulator:
[image]